# How to control the LinearLayout In the ScrollView In Android Eclipse?

Tags: android, eclipse, scrollview, android-linearlayout

Hi there I am in the middle of developing my app and am just curious to find out whether or not this is possible.
Ok so I have loads of text in my Layout and I want to pragmatically control where the linear layout in the scroll view has been pressed.
For example I want to program my app to go in the middle of my text how would I do that?

Comment: what do you mean you want the app to "go in the middle" of your text? also if you could post your xml that would help us to see what you're talking about.

Comment: Set Scroll for the TextView

Comment: You mean that you have a `ScrollView` as a parent for the `LinearLayout`?

Comment: yes @RotaryHeart that is what I mean

Comment: @Eluvatar it's just got loads of text on it nothing interesting I want to know how to change where the scroll is using code only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about using the "scrollTo" function.  Programatically you will be able to specify the x and y to scroll to.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html#scrollTo(int, int)

Here is an example of how to use the scrollBy and scrollTo methods.  Essentially you give it an offset in pixels for the amount you want to scroll.  You can use getScrollX and getScrollY to get positions, though it sounds in your case you might want to use "scrollBy" to scroll an offset based on the top of the scroll view and where the user pressed.

http://android-er.blogspot.com/2011/09/scroll-view-scrollby-and-scrollto.html

Comment: could you show me how to use this please as android developer site does really show me everything?

Comment: @MikeyBoy I've edited the answer above to point to a blog entry about how to use the scrollTo and scrollBy methods.  Let me know if this helps.